# How to push authentication code to production server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

I have realms authenticator and loginmodule in development server . I want to know how to push these things to production server.

Comment: Please describe your problem in a bit more detail, what have you tried already? What effect did that give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're building your application in MobileFirst Studio this action will generate a .war file. The .war file contains the authentication configuaration.

You deploy this .war file as part of the move to the production environment.

You can find more information about the flow, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/moving-production/moving-development-environment-stand-alone-qa-production-servers/

Comment: Is there any possibility I can push .war through CLI, if I have admin credentials to the enterprise server.